# Pandas Forward Backward fill on columns within column level

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe: df

```
                     name  width  length
timestamp                           
2019-08-01 00:00:08    10   10.0     NaN
2019-08-01 00:00:19    10    NaN     NaN
2019-08-01 00:00:56    10    NaN     86.0
2019-08-01 00:00:08    12    NaN     90
2019-08-01 00:00:19    12   12.0     NaN
2019-08-01 00:00:28    12    NaN     NaN
```

I would like to apply forward and backward fill on the columns 'width' and 'length' within for the column 'name'. The result would look like this:

```
                     name  width  length
timestamp                           
2019-08-01 00:00:08    10   10.0     86
2019-08-01 00:00:19    10   10.0     86
2019-08-01 00:00:56    10   10.0     86
2019-08-01 00:00:08    12   12.0     90
2019-08-01 00:00:19    12   12.0     90
2019-08-01 00:00:28    12   12.0     90
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: How do you decide how many rows forward to take the first `10.0` in the `'width'` column?  You show it going 2 rows forward then allowing the `12.0` to go back 1 row.  How do you make that decision?

Comment: Is there only ever at most one non-null value for each column within each `'name'`?

Comment: I was not clear about this maybe; for the same unique value in 'name' there is one 'width' and one 'length' value, which I want to want to bfill/ffill because they are given for a later time. Name is always non-null, but ideally I would not have to matter in a pandas statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need `groupby` with `apply` , since we chain two functions `ffill` and `bfill` together

```
df.update(df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill()))
```

Comment: I think you're right... but this only works if the groups defined by `name` are contiguous.

Comment: @piRSquared Yes , you are right Sir ~ This solution assumed the name contiguous .

Comment: Why `name` need to be contiguous?

Comment: @QuangHoang because if it is not, then when you `ffill` you might skip rows weirdly.  For example, `df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 10), (1, None), (2, 20), (1, None)], columns=['name', 'width'])`.  If you do `df.groupby('name').width.ffill()` you fill in that last spot and I'm not sure if OP intends that.

Comment: That's exactly my point. I'm not sure if OP needs that, but as dictated *forward and backward fill... within the column "name"*, I do think that should be the case.

Comment: We're thinking about the same thing.  I just wanted to make sure OP thinks about that.

Comment: This solved my problem. "name" is indeed contiguous. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 1):

as you said each unique `name` has only one value of `width` and `length`, you may be able to avoid `apply` by using `transform` and `max` or `first`

```
df.update(df.groupby('name')[['width','length']].transform('max'))

Out[87]:
                     name  width  length
timestamp
2019-08-01 00:00:08    10   10.0    86.0
2019-08-01 00:00:19    10   10.0    86.0
2019-08-01 00:00:56    10   10.0    86.0
2019-08-01 00:00:08    12   12.0    90.0
2019-08-01 00:00:19    12   12.0    90.0
2019-08-01 00:00:28    12   12.0    90.0
```